# Python code has errors in old version of python?

Tags: python

I am running the same script on another server and it runs fine but have problems in the new server. Is it because the python version in the new server is outdated? Old version is Python Python 2.7.3 and new server has Python 2.6.6?

One of the error is this `Error was 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'` The code is below

```
#Area
    try:
        area= soup.find('div', 'location')
        result= str(area.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
        # print([area_result])
        area_result=cleanup(result).split('>')[2].split(";")[0]
        nearby_result=cleanup(result).split('>')[2].split(";")[1]
        # nearby_result=cleanup(area_result).split('>')
        print "Area : ",area_result
        print "Nearby: ",nearby_result

        # print "Nearby : ",nearby_result

    except StandardError as e:
        area_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print area_result
```

Comment: Probably not.  It appears that you have a flaw in your code and that, on the new server, some object is not getting loaded or set, leaving you with a None reference where your code expects an object.

Comment: Same code is working well in other server

Comment: So?  The other server surely has a completely different environment.  It's *possible* that a difference between 2.6 and 2.7 is causing an object to not get instantiated where you think it is, but it's more likely to be something *else* different between the two environments.  Show us the code -- the line where the error is thrown, and the line where the object is supposed to get instantiated.

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup? Compare library version on both sides.

Comment: how do i check? any suggestion?

Comment: From the Python shell, `import bs4; print bs4.__version__`

Comment: yes i am using beautiful soup

Comment: beautiful soup is same (4.3.2) but python versions are different

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `soup.find` is returning None where you think it's finding an instance of a div called location.  This is most likely due to the your not having the same file to operate on, or perhaps having the file in a different location than you think.  Your code should check the result of `soup.find` before assuming it's successful.

There is a *possibility* of versionitis here but it's more likely that the input is different.  Have you checked which version of Beautiful Soup is installed on the two systems (I assume that's what `soup` is referencing).

Comment: beautiful soup is same (4.3.2) but python versions are different

Comment: Where are you getting the input to `soup`?  From a web site or from a file?  Check the contents of what's going *into* `soup` on both servers.  It's likely not the same content.

Comment: http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-sale/residential/apartment/ This is the website

Comment: No, I mean *in your code* check the contents that you have retrieved and are feeding into the instance of `soup` you are using for processing.  Compare the size of the input on the two systems, your print the input to the console and inspect it visually.  I suspect you will see different content on each server -- perhaps no content at all on the newer server (in which case the problem is the server's ability to retrieve the web page).

Comment: So, why do you think each server receives different content?  Can you tell by looking at the contents of each retrieved document?

Comment: I have 2 extractions open. One gives the location but the other doesnt. Have no idea why its like this

Comment: There are a very large number of reasons why this may be true.  You may be using a slightly different URL to access the page.  You may be using different credentials to log in to the web site, one of which allows you to get locations, the other doesn't.  The two servers may be based in different locations and the server you're talking to may look at the incoming IP address and decide to show you different versions of the page depending on the location origin of the incoming request.

Comment: Do you have access to a browser on each server.  I'd use that, or CURL, to ensure you can receive the same page on each server.  Until you have that solved, no purpose in trying to solve the problem in Python.